# тупит background-position при @keyframes

Tags: css-animation, keyframes

задал на фоновую картинку через background-image размер 2560 × 1440 px
задал движение по горизонтали через @keyframes, изображение дергается, что с этим делать? и еще один момент: у меня бургер меню и в нем анимированые ссылки при клике на иконку меню срабатывает класс active для ссылок и они дергаються пока идет анимация, НО стоит отключить свойство animation для background-image ссылки анимируются нормально,как решить данную проблему? https://stroy.art/ ссылка на сайт

```
.slider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 animation: scroll linear 100s infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {   
      opacity: 0;          
      background-position: left 0;
      
    }
    2%{
        opacity: 1; 
    }

    100%{       
        background-position: right 0;
    }
}
```

вот код бургер меню код на scss

```
.menu-list-active{
        left: 0;

        li{
            animation: slide-in 1900ms backwards;
            animation-delay: 800ms;
        }


        

    }
    @keyframes slide-in {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateY(40px);
        }
        
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateY(0);
            
        }
           
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Каниф Таймасов Зачем вообще анимация нужна. Как показывает практика пользователей она раздражает. Они нажав кнопку хотят видеть действие, а не ждать когда начнется анимация, затем закончится и потом будет действие?! Анимация в данном действии это прошлый век, в жесткую, только в жесткую надо делать. На мобильниках анимация будет кушать ресурсы.

Comment: @Arcadiy красиво же когда она появляется, без анимации скучно, а есть какие нибудь решения что бы было мене ресурсо емко ?

Comment: @Эникейщик переименовал